# Wpf UserControl Width and Height Not Taknig

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a user control that is just a box with text like this:

```
<Border x:Name="box" 
            BorderThickness="0"
            BorderBrush="Black" 
            Background="Black"
            Width="200" Height="200">

    <Label Content="Hello World" 
               Height="65"  Width="400"
               Foreground="White" FontSize="32"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
</Border>
```

When I create and instance of it in my MainWindow like this...

`<local:MyBoxControl Width="1000" Height="1000"/>`

the width and height is 200x200 as defined in the `Border` when I'd like it to be 1000x1000 as provided when I create it.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the Width and Height from the Border element.

Comment: Thank you, that along w/ the Alignment thing fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be acceptable for you to set the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment of the Border to Stretch?

Comment: That did it along w/ @Joel Lucsy's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need the width/height of the border to remain at 200 (otherwise you just wouldn't specify it) you can make a grid the outermost element of the control and put the border inside it. Then if you don't define a width/height on that it will auto-adjust to the size of your control.

```
<Grid>
    <Border x:Name="box"  
                BorderThickness="0" 
                BorderBrush="Black"  
                Background="Black" 
                Width="200" Height="200"> 

        <Label Content="Hello World"  
                   Height="65"  Width="400" 
                   Foreground="White" FontSize="32" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" /> 
    </Border> 
</Grid>
```